# Python reading chunks of text

Tags: python, parsing, scanning

I am running into some problems trying to read a file correctly.

I only have a code to show what I'm trying to aim for slightly. But I want to read each chunk of data (four lines) and insert each of those chunks into an array. I also need to separate 'city', 'state', and 'zip' from each other.

I understand that I'm supposed to read the file, for each chunk I read until an empty line, within that I would check to see if it is the third line and if so parse each part into its own element, and do all that till the end. I am, however, having trouble with the coding part with Python. I am not too familiar with Python.

My data:

```
Name
address
city, state zip
phone number
//empty line
Name
address
....
```

My code:

```
with open('tester_everything.txt') as f:                                                                                                                  
mylist = []                                                                                                                                             
i=0                                                                                                                                                     
for lines in f:                                                                                                                                         
  other_list = []        
  if lines == '\n':
    mylist.append(other_list)
    other_list = []

  other_list.insert(i, lines)                                                                                                                    
  i = i+1                                                                                                                                               
print mylist                                                                                                                                            
f.close()
```

This creates all empty elements inside mylist.

Comment: You got `other_list` emptied before saving it. Delete the first `other_list = []` after the `for` and rewrite it after the `with`.

Comment: Is:`city, state zip`    or    `city, state, zip` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open('tester_everything.txt') as f:                                                                                                                  
    mylist = []  
    other_list = []                                                                                                                                                   
    for lines in f:                                                                                                                                         
        if lines == '\n':
            mylist.append(other_list)
            other_list = []
        else:
            other_list.append(lines)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    print mylist
```

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe I was forgetting about the else statement now that I see it.
If I wanted to then parse that third line of data would I just add another if/else statement within the else statement?

Comment: Yes. You can set a counter like `count = 0` before the `for`, and reset it to zero `if lines == '\n'` and add 1 otherwise. Then you can add `if count == 2;` (third line) and complete your code.